# Resource not found java

Tags: java, exception, opengl, lwjgl

I am building a tower defense game in Java using the lwjgl and slick2D libraries with maven building tool.

I get a RuntimeException for a resource not found **pictures/dirt.png**. I have double checked the path and everything that is related to the lines of code where the error might be linked to but I am stuck.

Below is the hierarchy picture of my project with all the pictures and the error.

I haven't found a this problem posted so I'm asking for help.

[image]

Here is the picture of my output where I get the error.

[image]

And finally, methods for loading pictures are here.

[image]

This is my main method and the class where I call these methods.

[image]

Here are the maven classes, just in case.
[image]

Comment: Could you post code instead of screenshots please?

Comment: @Erik i would like but as you can see there a lot of code which need to be provided and the question will look like more confusing. If you want to i can provide the code somewhere else.

Comment: It shouldn't be to hard as long as you follow StackOverflow's guidelines for formatting your post. Be sure to use the tools provided to you to format your post.

Answer (score 2):

Maven need to know which resource to package. In your case, I would suggest updating your `pom.xml` to add resource directive for Maven to include resource files such as image, text, and etc.

**EDIT Update** Added directory after knowing exact location for PNG files.

```
<project>
    ...
    <build>
        ...
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java/pictures</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.png</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        ...
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

Comment: I have updated post, because of your suggestion and what i did i have just uploaded picture of my pom.xml because i dont know where exactly to point my picture package.

Comment: That's a good screenshot. I'd prefer text-based but that's okay. I note your `pom.xml` is missing resource tag. Go ahead and add `<build>` tag with my suggestion and rebuild project `mvn clean install` before trying again.

Comment: I tried bro here is the link of my Google-drive where i have screenshot the current condition. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jBdMhUN3zVnhlEWgGRwoEGoNeuz8z7Jn

Comment: I'm not familiar with NetBeans because I'm unsure whether Source Package is named `src`. Your build tag is in correct place, we could improve the syntax after we have this fixed. I suspect the error lies in defining file and folder path. Could you provide a full path to your `pictures` folder shown in screenshot?

Comment: Of course, just a second.

Comment: I did what you say but its not working. Here is a link https://drive.google.com/open?id=1F-L9VnZ4k3PyZ54_tx2w41BecXZUCDOv .Maybe this would be interesting for you to hear. I made new project but without maven. The same classes everything like this project and when i run it, the pane is opened but the whole screen on it is black, but there isn't any error. Maybe this could help in some way.

Comment: I faced the same issue in different Maven projects when resource is not available. From my end, I usually use `src/main/resources` as directory name and specify file extension to package in jar. From your screenshot, I think we're missing couple of folder names. What is the full path to your `dirt.png`, i.e., `C:\Users\someone\projects\tower_defense_game\pictures\dirt.png`?

Comment: Okey its: C:\Users\miskecpro\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TD\src\main\java\pictures\dirt.png

Comment: Bingo. Update `<directory>` tag using this value: `src/main/java/pictures`. Rebuild `mvn clean install` and I'm 99% certain this should work.

Comment: Huh i have updated it but its not working again :( . Here is a link https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tHeHedSiVhgtNwCl1L0IS-oVJDeS_Khk. I was thinking of putting my project on drive i am gonna do that to help you and me.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IO0MbheYenLXUYlG1DeaaTvxyq8Lj2Ke  Here we go. Experiment as i did.

Comment: Thanks @Milos. I'll look into the file and see what's causing the issue. we'll get you a solution. sit tight.

Comment: Okey bro i found a solution, there is nothing about the pom.xml. The whole story was about the path. It should be like this. Focus on loadTexture1 method  tex = loadTexture("C:\\Users\\miskecpro\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\TD\\src\\main\\java\\pictures\\" + putanja + ".png", "PNG");

Comment: But now I am pretty sure that this will only runs on my computer, because this path is not the same at everyone's computer right?

Comment: Anyway you took a lot of your time trying to fix my problems so you need to be rewarded. Thanks for everything, i mean if you have a solution for improving this path, feel free to share.

Comment: This will only work on your computer and is not portable. I suspect it's path issue. A good practice is to use file path from project root folder. This way application can run on other computers.

Comment: Do you know how its gonna look like ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169708/discussion-between-dorado-and-milos).

Answer (score 0):

try to print current working directory in loadTexturel1 method and try to adjust your path accordingly.
String current = new java.io.File( "." ).getCanonicalPath()
see if that help

Comment: I have tried what you have suggested but it wont works.

Comment: ok, did you also try data/pictures/ instead of just pictures?

Comment: I found the solution the right path is just the name of the picture and the extension but nothing before the name either the package name